# Pandas apply across multiple columns such that common calculations (across different columns) happen only once

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, apply

This isn't the actual use case - has been simplified for ease of understanding.

Consider a df as below

[image]

I have to get a score for each column which is found by ***(entry in that column) * (sum across the respective row)***. So for df.loc[0,'a'] , the calculation will be as below:

`df.loc[0,'a'] *  (df.loc[0,'a']+df.loc[0,'b']) = 1 * (1+4) = 5`

The code for the above is:

```
df['a_score'] = df.apply(lambda x:(x['a']+x['b'])*x['a'],axis=1) 
df['b_score'] = df.apply(lambda x:(x['a']+x['b'])*x['b'],axis=1)
```

And the output is as below:

[image]

**Problem**: As you can clearly see, I have to calculate the sum for each row twice (once for Column:`a_score` and the second time for Column:`b_score`)

**Question**: Is there a way this can be avoided - i.e. only calculate the sum for each row only once and use it moving forward? For example here, calculate the sum for each row while creating Column:`a_score`  and reuse this sum while creating Column:`b_score`.

One obvious way is to store the sum for each row as a different column and do this before calculating the `a_score` and `b_score` columns. The code for this is below:

```
df['sum'] = df.apply(lambda x:x['a']+x['b'],axis=1)
df['a_score'] = df.apply(lambda x:x['sum'] * x['a'],axis=1) 
df['b_score'] = df.apply(lambda x:x['sum'] * x['b'],axis=1)
```

But ^ solution can't be used due to the constraints I have with my current structure of the code wherein I cannot create a new column in the data frame nor can I create a new data frame.

Comment: your code doesn't match your description. `df['a_score'] = df.apply(lambda x:(x['a']*x['a'])+x['a'],axis=1)` is `a^2 + b`, which is not the same as `a * (a + b)` (that's `a^2 + a*b`). which is it? in any case, why not just create a new series? and don't use apply here. `scores = df.mul(df.sum(axis=1), axis=0)` seems like it should do the trick.

Comment: @MichaelDelgado My bad - have edited it now.  I don't have the freedom to create a new series / dataframe unfortunately due to the limitations in the current code

Comment: I mean as a temporary variable. then you could could do `for c in scores.columns: df[f"{c}_score"] = scores[c]`.

Comment: similarly, in your example, you could just assign a temporary variable `summed` instead of assigning `df["sum"]`. but please don't use `df.apply` when a vectorized option is so much easier and faster.

Answer (score 2):

Since you want to use `apply` you can pass custom function to it and return/set values to multiple columns simultaneously row by row

```
def get_val(x):
    sum_var = x['A'] + x['B']
    val_a = x['A'] * sum_var
    val_b = x['B'] * sum_var
    
    return val_a, val_b
          
df[['a_score','b_score']] = df.apply(lambda x: get_val(x), axis=1, result_type="expand")
```

OR just do this (to operate with columns instead of rows):

```
sum_var = df['A'] + df['B']
df['a_score'] = df['A'] * sum_var
df['b_score'] = df['B'] * sum_var
```